# how to get the index number in R

Tags: r

First,there is a dataframe,like `df = data.frame(a = c("one","two"),b = c(1,2),c = c(3,4))`,I want to get rid of some columns which is no use,I knew I can use `df[-1]`,if I don't use column `a`,however,if i rearrange the column order,I have to know the index number of `a` is `1` or `2` or another number,how can I do?

thanks any help in advance~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `name` of the column itself instead of its index number. There are several ways to do this, but I prefer `setdiff` to things like `-(which(...))`.

```
df[, setdiff(names(df), "a")]
#   b c
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
```

For "interactive use", there's also `subset`:

```
subset(df, select=-a)
#   b c
# 1 1 3
# 2 2 4
```

---

As indicated, though, the most direct answer to your question "how to get the index number...", `which` does that for you:

```
which(names(df) == "a")
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much,if do that with the second way with which expression,how to achieve?Thanks~~~

Comment: @Lawes, I showed that already in the first paragraph. `-which()`, thus, `df[-which(names(df) == "a")]`. However, this would not give you the expected results if you searched for a name that didn't exist, for example: `df[-which(names(df) == "z")]`. The only one that handles this nicely is the `setdiff` approach.